# Is the following optimization problem convex? If not, what is it?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Sorry if the question is trivial. 
I have the following optimization problem which I think is not convex because of the binary constraints. But I do not know what is this problem then. Here is the optimization problem.

$$
\text{minimize }  ||Ax - b||_2 \\
s.t. 
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} x_i = \ell,\\
x \in \lbrace 0,1\rbrace
$$

In fact, the goal is to only select $\ell$ points from $A$, such that the sum of those selected points is close to $b$.

Comment: Your objective is currently a vector-valued function. Do you want to add some norm to that, or is this a multi-objective problem?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I actually edited the objective function now, minimize L2 norm of $Ax-b$. Any help is appreciated on what is this problem and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a mixed-integer second order cone optimization problem. MOSEK is arguably the best solver for this problem. If $\ell$ is small, you could brute-force the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @LinAlg and Beached Whale. I have another question as well. Let's say I consider a relaxed version of this problem by removing the binary constraints. Is this relaxed version a CVX optimization problem?

Comment: Yes, that's a second order cone optimization problem (which is convex). MOSEK solves the integer problem by solving a sequence of relaxed problems (with $0\leq x_i\leq1$).

Comment: What is it exactly? quadratic linear programming? Or semi-definite quadratic?

Comment: A second order cone optimization problem (or a convex quadratic optimization problem if you will).